# read content from serial port and do check in C#

Tags: c#

I use windows 7 and VS 2017.
I want to read serial port and check if contains“GPIO42, md=0, input , di=1”.

But the judgement is wrong（the return command does contains "GPIO42, md=0, input , di=1" but the test_result still equals to fail）.

```
           serialPort1.WriteLine("AT+EGPIO=GPIO_GET:0~81\0d\0a");


            long last_time = DateTime.Now.Ticks / 10000;
            string indata = "";
            for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++)
            {
                long now_time = DateTime.Now.Ticks / 10000;

                if ((now_time - last_time) > 10000)
                {
                    break;
                }

                indata += serialPort1.ReadLine();

            }      











            if (!checkBox1.Checked)
            {
                if (!indata.Contains("GPIO42, md=0, input , di=1"))
                {
                    test_result = "FAIL";
                }
            }
```

Comment: serialPort it’s cmd?

Comment: You won't get a 1000 lines of text in response.  So it will eventually just hang on the ReadLine() call.  The command you use is non-standard so it isn't obvious how to break out of the loop when there is no more data.  AT-commands typically use "OK", so you could use var line = serialPort1.ReadLine(); if (line == "OK") break; indata += line;  If desperate then you can set the ReadTimeout property so the exception can get you out.

Comment: In most cases `ReadLine` from something like a device (serial port, network, etc) is not a good idea. You should check first, whether data is available and try to read as much data as is available. In your case `ReadLine` hangs til eternity if no complete line is received.

Comment: You have to exit the for loop when indata contains the end of line (0x0a).